# Acessing a variable being updated

Tags: python, csv

I have a function that watches a csv file. It iterates through all the lines in a csv file and returns each line, waits for the file to be updated, and if it is, returns that new value. This is how it looks like:

```
def follow():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    with open(file_path) as csvDataFile:
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
        csvDataFile.seek(0,0)
        while True:
            line = csvDataFile.readline()
            if not line:
                time.sleep(0.5)
                continue
            yield line
```

I am doing this for a gui. I have a button that, when pressed, loads the csv file and calls this function. It saves each line to a list that is a member variable.

```
def browseForFile(self):
        line = pull_csv_data.follow()
        for item in line:
            self.list.append(item)
```

When another button is pressed, it iterates through that list and displays the information on the gui:

```
def listItems(self):
    for i in self.list:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        item = QListWidgetItem(i)
        self.prev_scenes.addItem(item)
```

The problem is, whenever I click the button to display the data in the list, it stops responding until I kill the python script that has the `follow()` function. For clarification, the `follow` function is in a separate file that I include in my "main" file.

Essentially.. the follow function does not allow for other processes to run at the same time, I think. Is that true? is there a workaround? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Paste the properly indented code, swipe it with mouse and use Ctl-k or the `{}` tool to mark it as pre-formatted code.

Comment: Show the code that calls `follow()`.

Comment: Why aren't you using `csvReader`?

Comment: There's no need for `csvDataFile.seek(0, 0)`. When you open a file for reading, you default to the beginning of the file.

Comment: If you want multiple things to run at the same time you need to use threads.

Answer (score 1):

The follow function is in the same process as your main function. Because of this, when your follow function sleeps, so does your entire program. If you want this to be run asynchronously, you'll have to make it do so explicitly.

You should probably use something like https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/index.html or https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki instead of trying to write your own file handling function.

Comment: How could I get inotify to detect if the file is updated?